# ConnectionError in connecting my python code which is in windows os to my hdfs which is in linux os

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am new to using hdfs. I have stored couple of datasets there. Now I have a running code in Python which is in my local machine. I want to connect to the hdfs in the linux os in the code itself.
I have gone through some of the documentations and have made the necessary changes to the code as follows:

python-code.py:

```
# Set HDFS client
client = InsecureClient('http://192.168.131.129:9000', user='******')

# Function to find the answer based on similarity matching
def find_answer(question):
    # Load questions and answers from .dat files
    with client.read('/ana/questions.dat') as reader:
        questions = [line.strip() for line in reader.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()]

    with client.read('/ana/answers.dat') as reader:
        answers = [line.strip() for line in reader.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()]
```

However everytime I am getting the error as follows:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.131.129', port=55453): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/ana/questions.dat?user.name=******&offset=0&op=OPEN (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001C3222EA770>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

I have checked my Namenodes using jps as follows:

```
56144 NodeManager
60593 Jps
56021 ResourceManager
55787 SecondaryNameNode
55453 NameNode
55581 DataNode
```

I have also made the necessary changes to my `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml`.

Here is my **core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/aviparna/hdata</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Here is a screenshot that my hdfs web ui is running properly:
[image]

How to connect between these two?

Comment: Use pyspark, not WebHDFS

Comment: Unfortunately the requirement is for WebHDFS.

Comment: Strange requirement when you're just reading files... But I'd start with setting `192.168.131.129:9000` in the XML file rather than localhost. Then you need to ensure the namenode and python client can reach each of the datanodes on the network. Specifically, `port=55453` mentioned in the error